# Bukkit plugin - check if specific data from a file exists, and declare it

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft, bukkit

I'm having an issue with a bukkit plugin I'm updating. In what I'm doing, when a player uses a bed, it saves the following data to a file named `beds.yml`:

```
ThePlayersUsername:
    X: (double)
    Y: (double)
    Z: (double)
    world: worldName
```

When the plugin is initialized, I need to declare a few variables, because they are used later on in the code.

```
Player p = (Player)sender;
String dn = p.getDisplayName();
dn = ChatColor.stripColor(dn);
double x = (Double) yml.get(dn + ".x");
double y = (Double) yml.get(dn + ".y");
double z = (Double) yml.get(dn + ".z");
World bw = Bukkit.getWorld((yml.get(dn + ".world").toString()));
Location l = new Location(bw, x, y, z);
```

I can't do this if they don't exist, but, I can't reset to any defaults because new items get added to the config each time someone enters a bed, and all data is user-specific.

How would I go about checking if the player has some data in the config, if not, telling them to sleep in a bed, and when they do have data in the config, how to declare it so they can use a command to teleport using data from the config. Thanks.

Comment: What approaches have you tried and why don't they work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 list or array:

-The online players

-The players in the config

A simple string list is do the magic just store the names. Then compare them. Something like that:

```
List<String> online_players = new List<String>();
//fill list code here

List<String players_in_config = new List<String>();
//fill list code here

List<String> output = new List<String>();

for(String s : online_players){
    for(String a : players_in_config){
        if(s.equals(a)){
            output.add(s);
        break;
        }
    }
}

//and now output contains the names of the players that online and have a bed in the config
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use a `Map` here. Maps are a data structure that creates key-value pairs for your data. You can ask a `Map` for the data associated with a given key and you will get the value you put into it, or null if they key was not found.

Your map would look something like this:

```
private Map<Player, Location> bedLocations = new HashMap<Player, Location>();
```

We are going to store this data inside your JavaPlugin class since it needs access inside your listener and command handler. You will also need a way to get this `Map` from within your listener. An accessor method will do the job here. See the below method for how to do this. You will need to do it later as well.

```
public Map<Player, Location> getBedLocations() {
    return bedLocations;
}
```

In case you were wondering, a `HashMap` is a type of map that used the `int hashCode()` method to quicken key value access, but that's a more high level topic that's irrelevant to the issue at hand.

That map should store a key-value pair of all Players currently online that have a bed location associated with them. Since you don't need someone's info until they come online, you shouldn't load out of the configuration yet, but you should still open the configuration like so to prevent reading the file every time. This should be done in the onEnable method.

```
//Near your map and other class variables
private FileConfiguration bedConfiguration;

//Inside your onEnable
bedConfiguration = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(new File(PLUGIN_VARIABLE.getDataFolder(), "beds.yml"));
```

Don't forget to store that bedConfiguration in a class variable. Also create an accessor method for it. I would name it `getBedConfiguration()`.

Now you have a loaded configuration and a place to store your data, what next? You need to populate your `Map` with player data when they join.

Inside your listener, you should write a method to listen for the `PlayerJoinEvent`. Inside here you will load your player data.

Firstly, we need to get the YML file from our JavaPlugin class.

```
FileConfiguration bedConfig = plugin.getBedConfiguration();
```

That will get you the FileConfiguration that you opened up earlier. Now we check to see if the player's data is in the config.

```
if (bedConfig.isSet(event.getPlayer().getName()) {
    //Next section here
}
```

If the isSet method returns true, then something exists there. Now we load the data.

```
String playerName = event.getPlayer.getName(); //You can do this above the if statement if you wish.
double x = (Double) bedConfig.get(playerName + ".x");
double y = (Double) bedConfig.get(playerName + ".y");
double z = (Double) bedConfig.get(playerName + ".z");
World bw = Bukkit.getWorld((bedConfig.get(dn + ".world").toString()));
Location loc = new Location(bw, x, y, z);
```

Your data is loaded! Excellent. Now we store it in the map for later access. First, get the `Map` from the `JavaPlugin` class. Then we put our data into the `Map`.

```
Map<Player, Location> map = plugin.getBedLocations();
map.put(event.getPlayer(), loc);
```

The data is in the map! To access it, make sure you get the map first and then call `map.get(PLAYER);`

Other things that need to be done are... saving the data when a player leaves / the server shuts down and removing the player from the map when they leave (Keeping players in a map is a very bad practice, you can use their name or UUID as a key if you wish to prevent that issue).

To save your `Map` to the config, you can either change the config whenever a bed location changes, or you can wait and loop over all the `Map` entries and save them all at the end. To loop over these you can use an advanced for loop.

```
for(Player player : map.keySet()) {
    Location loc = map.get(player);
    //save here
}
```

This will loop over all players in the map and let you access their location with the `map.get(player)` method.

To remove a player from the map, listen for the `PlayerQuitEvent` and use `map.remove(player);` to unload their data. Don't forget to save it first if you don't save it every update.

If you have any questions, please leave a comment. I tried to be very thorough.